# Misunderstanding proof of bound on chromatic number of integer distance graphs

Tags: graph-theory, coloring

Given a subset $D$ of positive integers, we let the distance graph $G(Z,D)$ be the graph with vertex set $\mathbb{Z}$ and where an edge connects two integers whose absolute difference is in $D$.

[This](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/%28SICI%291097-0118%28199708%2925%3A4%3C287%3A%3AAID-JGT6%3E3.0.CO%3B2-G) paper contains the following theorem: If $D$ is finite, then $\chi(G(Z,D))\le |D|+1$.

Here is the proof the paper provides:

We color the vertices in $G(Z,D)$ recursively as follows. First, $f(0)=1$. When $f(j)$ are defined for $-i\le j\le i$, let $f(i+1)$ be the minimum positive integer not in
$A=\{f(j):-i\le j\le i$ and $i+1-j\in D\}$ and $f(-i-1)$ the minimum positive integer not in $B=\{f(j):-i\le j\le i $ and $j+i+1\in D\}$. $f$ is clearly a proper coloring for $G(Z,D)$. Note that $|A|\le |D|$ and $|B|\le|D|$ imply that $f(i+1) \le |D|+1$ and $f(-i-1) \le |D|+1$. So $f$ is a proper $(|D|+1)$-coloring. $\blacksquare$

I am able to follow the proof until the second to last sentence. I agree with the implication given, but the I don't see why the condition $|A|\le |D|$ and $|B|\le |D|$ should be true. Indeed, if $D=\{1,\ldots, n\}$ and $i>n$, then isn't $|A|=|B|=|D|+1>|D|$?

This paper/theorem is cited by other papers on the same topic, so I assume the proof must be correct. What am I misunderstanding?

Comment: Edited, should have been $f(i+1)$

Comment: Does the definition of $A$ imply that for every element $f(j)$ of $A$, $i+1-j \in D$, so that $|A|\le |D|$?

Comment: I'm not following, how would $\forall f(j)\in A, i+1-j\in D$ imply $|A|\le |D|$? If you're not asking rhetorically, no, I see no reason for that implication.

Comment: I could be wrong, but it seems like the definition of $A$ is saying, “if $-i\le j \le i$, and $i+1-j \in D$, then $f(j) \in A$.” The number of $j$ that satisfy that must be $\le |D|$

Comment: Ok yeah I think that makes sense, my conceptual understanding of $A$ was missing the "and $i+1-j\in D$" part. Thanks!

Comment: You’re welcome.

Comment: I think the definition of $B$ should be  $B=\{f(j):-i \le j \le \color{red}{i+1}, j+i+1 \in D\}$ to make sure that $f(i+1)$ and $f(-i-1)$ don't get the same color when $2i+2 \in D$. But that doesn't invalidate the proof, $|B| \le |D|$ still.